# Improve performance when eagerly querying tree-like structures with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, hibernate, jpa

We have this four tables persisting tree-like structures in Oracle, and we are using Hibernate to handle the persistence dirty job. It works pretty well in almost all scenarios , except for querying a bunch of those structures to transfer it as a JSON. It is taking something like 30 seconds to retrieve something like 3k entities, so I tried to investigate further.

The entities looks like this (a lot of code ommited for brevity):

```
@Table(name = "ROOT")
public class Root {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "root")
    @Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<Stem> stems;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "root")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<Branch> branches;
}

@Table(name = "STEM")
public class Stem {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOT_ID")
    private Root root;


}

@Table(name = "BRANCH")
public class Branch {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ROOT_ID")
    private Root root;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "branch")
    private List<Leaf> leaves;
}

@Table(name = "LEAF")
public class Leaf {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BRANCH_ID")
    private Branch branch;
}
```

The tests were performed with 25 `Root`s, a little less than 200 `Branch`es and a little more than 3k `Leaf`ves. Also, two and a half hundreds of `Stem`s were present.

Reading the logs, looks like for me that Hibernate permorms a *DFS*, that leads to a high number of queries (apparently, one for each entity) being fired.

So, I tried to implement a *BFS* (in Python, for brevity), by firing one query for each of the four tables. Surprisingly, I was able to have the same JSON ready in less than a half second (including the time for `json.dump` it all)! The script was something like this (similarly repeated to all relations):

```
cur.execute('select * from PARENT_TABLE')
parents = parent_tuples_to_dict(cur.fetchmany(25))

cur.execute(f'select * from CHILD_TABLE where PARENT_ID in ({",".join([p[id] for p in parents])})')
children = child_tuples_to_dict(cur.fetchall())

for child in children.values():
  parent = next(p for p in parents if p['id'] == child['parent_id'])
  parent['children'].append(child)
```

I was considering just changing the DAOs to perform a *BFS* too, using `@SqlResultSetMapping` and *native queries*, but this looks like a pretty ugly solution. Besides, I believe I would need to manage the entities by myself to prevent memory leaks.

My questions are:

**Question #1:** could be the cause for this performance abism something we are doing wrong (I tried to resume all relevant details about the entities, but I can bring more, if needed)?

**Question #2:** what is the right/pretty way to do this kind of query with JPA / Hibernate / Named queries etc?

**Question #3:** if handling this "by hand" really become the most performatic solution, will I really need to manage the entities "by hand" too, to prevent memory leaks?

Answer (score 1):

## My solution

So... I found out with the help of some colleagues from a Facebook group that this is kind of problem is called **N+1 queries**, and it's kinda **common when working with ORM**.

My solution was to use the trick described at this article about [multiple bag fetch exception](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/) to take advantage of a persistence context behavior and achieve results simmilar to the ones I got with the Python script.

## How I solved it

Basically, once I have the parent table loaded (with the children marked as lazy), I *select* those very items again while doing a *join fetch* with the children table I want to load.

For the example I posted in my question, the solution is something like this:

```
void fetchWholeTree(List<Root> roots) {
    em.createNamedQuery("select distinct r " +
                        "from Root r " +
                        "left join fetch r.stems s " +
                        "where r in :roots")
            .setParameter("roots", roots)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();
    em.createNamedQuery("select distinct r " +
                        "from Root r " +
                        "left join fetch r.branches b " +
                        "where r in :roots")
            .setParameter("roots", roots)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();
    em.createNamedQuery("select distinct b " +
                        "from Root r " +
                        "left join r.branches b " +
                        "left join fetch b.leaves l " +
                        "where r in :roots")
            .setParameter("roots", roots)
            .setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false)
            .getResultList();
}
```

## Trying to answer the questions I left

**Question #1**: Yes. We were ignoring the N+1 queries scenario.

**Question #2**: Looks like (one of) the right way to solve N+1 queries with Hibernate is to work with `Hibernate::initialize` and `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`, but I was not able to find out how.

**Question #3**: Didn't had time to find it out, I have a strong feeling that it's possible to take a lot of advantage of the persistence context by just using `@SqlResultSetMapping`. If I ever try it out, I edit this answer with the results.